# Best event to save Vue.js appstate to localstorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications, vuejs2, local-storage

I'm trying to figure out the best way to save an apps state to local storage in order to be able to recreate it when returning to the app. Specifically this is for an iOS web app (i.e. saved to the users home screen). I'm *not* using Vuex as this is a simple application.

Currently I am using the `updated()` [Vue.js lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), but I feel like this is overkill, and perhaps a performance issue to be saving to local storage every single time the state changes:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',    
    updated: function() {
        this.saveAppState();
    }
});
```

*Note: the `saveAppState();` function above is where I'm using `localStorage.setItem()`.*

Apple's [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1) (see Table 6-1) suggests using `hidepage`, e.g.:

```
window.addEventListener('pagehide', function(event) {
    app.saveAppState();
}
```

However, this only works in mobile Safari when *reloading* the page. If I close the tab or when I add the app to my home screen, after quitting the app (hitting the home button) and returning, my state has not been saved.

I've also tried the `destroyed()` lifecycle hook, and that didn't work at all.

Any insight/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify whole idea. Assuming, state has been saved to localStorage in one way or another, how are you going to retrieve it upon next load to be accessible from any component?

Comment: I'm doing that using the `created()` Vue.js lifecycle hook.

Comment: if updated is too often, maybe a setInterval every x amount of time? it can check localStorage vs the application state, and if there's a difference, update localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one component that mutates the data, and have only a handful of data points, then just use a watch for each data item that may change.

> I'm not using Vuex as this is a simple application.

Vuex isn't just for handling a large *store*. That said, I've avoided using Vuex in smaller application, because handling the store distributed throughout the app and components was acceptable. I can't see the code or any details so YMMV, but... if you're not keen on using Vuex, you could still implement some aspects that would help with this problem.

1. Create a single store
   Having a unified location means that your various components *reference* your data, instead of storing it.
2. Mutate state through a unified/consistent interface
   any change to the state should come through either the same function, or a consistent pattern. This way you can easily hook to the data changes, so you update your localStorage *only when the data mutates*.

You can implement this using custom Vue function, or a bus, but easiest to do it with vuex.